# Exception when highlighting duplicates

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to highlight values in one column based on another column data. I have C1,C2 colums where for eg: 8A83-AA in both C1 and C2 has different Val1 and Val2 in some rows, if 8A83-AA(both occurrences) that matches val1 and val2 data then val1 highlight with green otherwise orange. The result should looks like

[image]

I've tried the code in stackoverflow

```
Sub Highlight_Duplicate_Entry()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim myrng As Range
Dim clr As Long
Dim lastCell As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set myrng = ws.Range("A2:d" & Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
With myrng
    Set lastCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
End With
myrng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
clr = 3

For Each cell In myrng
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myrng, cell) > 1 Then
        ' addresses will match for first instance of value in range
        If myrng.Find(what:=cell, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, after:=lastCell).Address = cell.Address Then
            ' set the color for this value (will be used throughout the range)
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = clr
            clr = clr + 1
        Else
            ' if not the first instance, set color to match the first instance
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = myrng.Find(what:=cell, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, after:=lastCell).Interior.ColorIndex
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

but it gives me exception object or block variable not set. I tried this range for one column at a time
   `Set myrng = ws.Range("A2:A600")`, it works. 
 but for multiple column 
   `Set myrng = ws.Range("A2:D600")` it is giving exception.
And how do i highlight which looks like in above picture data with VBA or conditional formating.

Comment: `Set myrng = ws.Range("A2:d" & Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)` should be `Set myrng = ws.Range("A2:d" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)` - that's what is probably causing your error.  But the code you are using will not do what you want it to do - all your code is doing is highlighting duplicate values within the range (e.g. all the `0` values will be set to have one colour, and all the `7`s will be set to another colour, etc.)

Comment: Just a technicality: VBA doesn't *throw exceptions*, it *raises errors*. I **wish** we had exceptions (and a frakkin' stack trace!!) in VBA =)

Comment: And `.Find` will return `Nothing` if there's no match, so calling `.Address` on the result without checking if there's actually an object reference there, is asking for the runtime error you're getting.

Comment: @YowE3K, can u give me an example code to get highlighted like in picture

Comment: @Mat'sMug - but considering that the `.Find` is only searching for something that is already known to be in `myrng` (i.e. searching within `myrng` for `cell` within a `For Each cell In myrng` loop) the `.Find` **should** always get a match.

Comment: @YowE3K right - I only merely skimmed through the code, that struck me as a good place for error 91 to be raised.

Comment: @sam - I can't write the code without knowing the full rules that you are trying to embed in the code (e.g. why is one `8A83-AA`'s value meant to be highlighted in orange while the other four are highlighted green?  why are none of the four `7L14-AA0014` values highlighted in green?).  Why don't you start writing the code and show us what you come up with and tell us which bits aren't working - we will have a much better chance of understanding your desired rules from seeing your first cut of the code than from reading your description.

Answer (score 0):

use a loop that will tell the cells in val1 from val2 if they are equal or not. Put your loop for val1 and search through val2.